# osx, openpam and location of .so modules?

Tags: macos, pam

I have developed a PAM module to run under openpam on osx 10.6.  I have created "linux-pam" modules in the past and I know where those shared objects should be installed.  It is obviously NOT in the same place for osx.  I spent some time doing "find"s in / on the target osx machine but could not locate the proper dir.  The docs I have seen for openpam have not yielded a clue.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

huh, they are in /usr/lib/pam.  Yuo can also specify the path in the /etc/pam* conf files.